# What is the best practice for major question re-write?

Tags: discussion, edits

If I ask a question that could have been asked more precisely had I had more information (or did not know the proper verbiage), then obtain said information what is the best practice for editing vs. creating a new question?

Example: [How can I obtain relevant params, classes, and methods from a .groovy script from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59796609/11019416)

When I initially asked the question, I did not have a great understanding of some of the Groovy API functions. Now, the basis of my question is the same, except I will be asking it in the context of "Evaluating a GroovyObject for methods, classes, params, etc..."

With no answers yet (only comments) I think editing it should be fine. If the root of the question remains the same, but I'm able to ask it more specifically (even if there were answers), should I edit it or create a new question?

Comment: Editting seems fine to me. It's when people ask a question, get (plenty of) correct answers, and then the OP says "Oh, I meant this" and completely changes the context that really annoys people. Comments can and do help to obtain clarity for a question, but when that's given you just need to ensure you migrate that information to the question and not leave it solely in the comments.